# Validate data on all associated models before saving any Django models

Tags: django, django-admin

I have two models in a Django project.  One of them has a foreignkey to the other and within the admin is displayed as an inline model so that we can work with both models together.

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    name = CharField(max_length=150)

class Model2(models.Model):
    parent = ForeignKey(Model1, on_delete=CASCADE)
    name = CharField(max_length=15)
```

My current goal is to be able to save Model1 in the admin and before any data is saved at all check all associated Model2 instances to make sure their 'name' field is not a certain value.  This would mean that if I changed the name of Model1 and created 2 Model2 instances I would check both Model2 instances for their name incoming name value, make sure it checks out, if both do not DO NOT save ANYTHING, if they both check out, save everything.

So far I have not found anything that will allow me to see the incoming values prior to saving Model1.  Instead, I can only check each incoming Model2 right before it is saved.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this by using Django pre_save signal for Model1 to check all associated Model2 instances before any data is saved.

For example, this should work:

```py
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

@receiver(pre_save, sender=Model1)
def check_model2_names(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    model2_instances = instance.model2_set.all()
    
    for model2_instance in model2_instances:
        if model2_instance.name == "certain_value":
            raise ValidationError("Name cannot be certain value")
```

Comment: I tried this but the model2 instances all have the data that is in the database still since they havn't been saved yet.